# Scala Monix , how to kill running or scheduled Task

Tags: scala, asynchronous, concurrency, future, monix

Im using [Monix](https://monix.io) for asynchronous task workflow.

How do we kill a running `Task` ?

```
Task{ println("sleep")
      Thread.sleep(200)
      println("effect") }
.doOnCancel(Task(println("canceled")))
.timeout(100.milli) // timeout will do cancel
.runOnComplete(println)
```

`@> Failure(java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Task timed-out after 100 milliseconds of inactivity)
sleep
canceled
effect <--- what !? , task is running. Isn't it canceled !?`

My current solution is ugly in my opinion(the flag checking hinders the code reusing):

```
var flag=true
Task{ 
      println("sleep")
      Thread.sleep(200)
      if (flag)
        println("effect") 
}
.doOnCancel(Task{ flag=false; println("canceled") })
.timeout(100.milli) // timeout will do cancel
```

---

If it is impossible, how do we kill a scheduled while not-yet-ran `Task` ?

My failed attempt is :

```
Task{ println("sleep"); Thread.sleep(200) }
.map{ _ => println("effect") }
.doOnCancel(Task(println("canceled")))
.timeout(100.milli) // timeout will do cancel
.runOnComplete(println)
```

Sadly it still shows the effect after the cancel happened. I hope that the scheduled and not-yet-ran Task can be canceled (the `.map(...)` is another `Task`, right?)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use `Thread.sleep` (which messes with the internals of Monix), but `Task.sleep`, things are working just fine.

```
Task
  .defer {
    println("start")
    Task.sleep(1000.millis)
  }
  .map(_ => println("effect"))
  .timeout(10.millis)
  .doOnCancel(Task(println("canceling")))
```

Now, the question is what's your actual use case, because I'm sure you used `Thread.sleep` just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I found one of solutions if it is chain of tasks:

```
Task{println("start");Thread.sleep(1000)}
 .asyncBoundary
 .map{_=> println("effect")}
 .doOnCancel(Task(println("canceling")))
 .timeout(10.milli)
 .executeWithOptions(_.enableAutoCancelableRunLoops)
 .runOnComplete(println)
```

reference: https://github.com/monix/monix/issues/226

But I hope there are easy way to **interrupt task** instead of using closure or split and chaining tasks.